Sistema de usuarios de lotería multinivel
estoy trabajando en un sistema de loterías con diferentes tipos de usuario:super usuario,cliente,banca,puestos y listeros,los clientes tienen bancas a su cargo,mi necesidad es en cierto tipos de sorteo,que se les llama sorteos base,el usuario tipo cliente puede ver los sorteos base creados por el mismo y por el super usuario,luego el usuario tipo banca puede ver los que el crea y los del cliente al que pertenece,ahora,a la hora de hacer consultas me tira más resultados de los que debería,mi problema es cómo armar las querys correctamente,específicamente a la hora de hacer búsquedas,que se hace por nombre,la estructura de la tabla es así:
  `id_sorteo_base` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario_base` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_sorteo` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text NOT NULL,
  `tipo_sorteo` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_asignacion_premio` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_cierre` date NOT NULL,
  `cierre_lunes` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cierre_martes` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cierre_miercoles` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `cierre_jueves` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cierre_viernes` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cierre_sabado` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cierre_domingo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `numeros_premiados` text NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `superior` int(15) NOT NULL

Y el código que uso es el siguiente:
Y este es el script que realiza las búsquedas:
<?php 
session_start();
include("conexion.php");
  if(isset($_POST['page'])){
    
include("Pagination.class.php");
include("dbConfig.php");
  

  $baseURL = 'getSorteosBaseCliente.php';
  $offset = !empty($_POST['page'])?$_POST['page']:0;
  $limit = 5;
  $uno = "1";
  
  // Set conditions for search
    $whereSQL = 'WHERE id_usuario_base = "'.$_POST['id_usuario'].'" OR id_usuario_base = "'.$_POST['superior'].'" ';
    #$whereSQL = 'WHERE TRUE';
    if(!empty($_POST['keywords']))
    {
        $whereSQL = $whereSQL. " AND nombre LIKE '%".$_POST['keywords']."%' ";
    }

     $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sorteos_base $whereSQL ORDER BY id_sorteo_base ASC ");
?>
    <!-- Data list container -->
    
    
        <?php
        if($query->num_rows > 0){?>
            <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
<tr>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Estado</th>
<th>Opciones</th>
</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php
            while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
                $offset++
        ?>
<tr>
<td><?= $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
<td><?= $row["estado"]; ?></td>
<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm actualizar" data-id="<?= $row['id_sorteo_base']; ?>"><i class='fas fa-edit'></i></button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete"  data-id="<?= $row['id_sorteo_base']; ?>"><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></button></td>
</tr>
            <?php
                    }
        
        }else{
            echo '<h2>No hay registros</h2>';
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>

Este es el contenido actual de la tabla sorteos base:
INSERT INTO `sorteos_base` (`id_sorteo_base`, `id_usuario_base`, `codigo_sorteo`, `nombre`, `descripcion`, `tipo_sorteo`, `tipo_asignacion_premio`, `fecha_cierre`, `cierre_lunes`, `cierre_martes`, `cierre_miercoles`, `cierre_jueves`, `cierre_viernes`, `cierre_sabado`, `cierre_domingo`, `numeros_premiados`, `estado`, `superior`) VALUES
(1, 1, 368856, 'Sorteo base 1', 'Sorteo base 1', 9, 15, '2024-12-06', '5:00 PM', '4:00 PM', '04:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '4:30 PM', '4:00 PM', '4:00 PM', '', 'Activo', 0),
(2, 1, 987248, 'Sorteo base 2', 'Sorteo base 2', 5, 4, '2024-12-17', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '03:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '45 Bolita: Roja', 'Activo', 0),
(3, 289, 162316, 'Sorteo base a', 'Sorteo base a', 4, 4, '2024-12-14', '5:00 PM', '4:30 PM', '04:30 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '', 'Activo', 1),
(5, 289, 730299, 'Sorteo base b', 'Sorteo base b', 6, 4, '2024-12-17', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '05:02 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '', 'Inactivo', 1),
(7, 306, 213621, 'Sorteo base 3', 'Sorteo base 3', 4, 1, '2024-12-14', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '05:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '5:00 PM', '', 'Activo', 289);

Gracias de antemano.

Te recomiendo ir al problema central y no añadir capas extras, especialmente cuando tienes problemas de este tipo... si crees que tu error está en el sql y la consulta, tu pregunta no necesita todo el php y html, solo el conjunto de tablas y, muy importante, datos de prueba y ejemplos de entrada/salida válidas. No somos adivino, y tampoco queremos estar media hora inventando datos para rellenar tus tablas y que al final no se parezcan...

O sea básucamente tienes escenarios en donde SELECT * FROM sorteos_base WHERE id_usuario_base = 1 OR id_usuario_base = 1 ORDER BY id_sorteo_base ASC  te da más resultados de los que debiera?

Así es,la búsqueda se hace por nombre,entonces si por ejemplo pongo 1 solo debería tirar sorteo base 1,que fue creado por el administrador,pero aparte de este me tira los otros dos que fueron creados por el usuario cliente @ffflabs edité la publicación para que veas el contenido actual de la tabla sorteos base

@Benito-B he actualizado el post con el contenido de la tabla

Y si solamente dejas los querys?? porque tu problema esta ahi, no en todo el resto del codigo...

Lo actualicé,dejé solo el script que hace las búsquedas @gbianchi

Sigo sin enteder tu problema. Yo miro solo el query, y ese query esta... raro... porque haces dos veces la busqueda por el mismo campo? y probaste ese query en tu db? con que parametros lo probaste?

Ese es justamente mi problema ,cómo hago para mostrar los sorteos creados por el cliente con la sesión activa y los creados por el administrador ?,es decir,por ejemplo yo como cliente puedo crear sorteos,puedo ver los que  yo haya creado y los creados por el super administrador @gbianchi

Probaste la query en la DB? con que parametros? que deberia devolverte???

No sé exactamente como armar la consulta,como ya te indiqué ese es mi problema si fuera solo mostrar los sorteos creados por mi mismo como cliente sería así: SELECT FROM sorteos_base
WHERE id_usuario_base = '289',ocupo que me muestre también los creados por mi superior @gbianchi

Perfecto.. entonces centremos tu pregunta en eso.. quien seria el superior??? tu pregunta es de base de datos pura... como obtenes quien es el superior?

El superior es el super admin,a la hora de registrar cada sorteo se almacena el id del usuario que lo crea,ese id se almacena también en la tabla usuarios,yo le llamé "superior",sería con una consulta con join cierto? @gbianchi

Puede que tu problema se deba a que esta mal armada la tabla... cada usuario tiene un superior distinto?

No,también  uno o más usuarios pueden tener el mismo superior @gbianchi

Entonces definitivamente hay un diseño erroneo en la tabla. Eso que buscas deberia estar en otra tabla donde tengas los usuarios y sus superiores. por eso tenes problemas con el query. De paso hay otros datos que parecerian no pertenecer a esa tabla. Esta en tercera forma normal?

Tercera forma normal ? no entiendo @gbianchi

Esa tabla, en esa base de datos, esta normalizada? porque todos tus problemas, parten desde ese punto...

Sí,cada campo es único @gbianchi

te veo en el [chat]. tu problema esta en otro lado, y es el diseño de la db segun comentas

No veo la opción para enviarte mensaje por el chat @gbianchi

El chat es publico.. entra ahi y cuando la gente pueda te va a ayudar...

Hola, estoy revisando el código ... intentaré ayudarte.

Tu problema radica en cómo estás estructurando las condiciones en tu cláusula WHERE. Ahora mismo, la condición permite demasiados resultados porque no considera la jerarquía correctamente, especialmente en cómo los usuarios deben ver los sorteos base.

tambien tengo que decir que gbianchi tiene parte de la razón...

Como lo dicen el los comentarios el problema está en la estructura de la base de datos. y en que en tu consulta no se toman correctamente las jerarquias.
Normalización de la Base de Datos
Se debería crear una tabla específica para manejar las relaciones entre usuarios (ejemplo: usuarios y superiores). Esto facilita las consultas jerárquicas y mejora la legibilidad:
CREATE TABLE jerarquias (
    id_usuario INT NOT NULL,
    id_superior INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_usuario, id_superior),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuarios(id_usuario),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_superior) REFERENCES usuarios(id_usuario)
);

Consulta Eficiente
Basado en la relación descrita, la consulta para obtener los sorteos debería usar un JOIN entre las tablas relacionadas. Por ejemplo:
SELECT sb.*
FROM sorteos_base sb
LEFT JOIN jerarquias j ON sb.id_usuario_base = j.id_usuario
WHERE (sb.id_usuario_base = ? OR j.id_superior = ?)
  AND sb.nombre LIKE ?;

nota: Esto permite incluir los sorteos creados por el cliente y por su superior.

Si el diseño de la base de datos no puede cambiarse, se puede intentar con subconsultas, pero esto puede ser menos eficiente. Un ejemplo:
SELECT * 
FROM sorteos_base
WHERE id_usuario_base = ? 
   OR id_usuario_base = (SELECT superior FROM usuarios WHERE id_usuario = ?)
   AND nombre LIKE ?;


Otra posible solución, sería aplicnado los principios desde el script PHP:

Superusuario: Puede ver todos los sorteos base.
Cliente: Puede ver sus propios sorteos y los del superusuario.
Banca: Puede ver sus propios sorteos y los del cliente al que pertenece.

nota: Puedes modificar el script para estructurar las consultas de acuerdo con el nivel de jerarquía de los usuarios
$whereSQL = "WHERE TRUE";

if (!empty($_POST['tipo_usuario'])) {
    $tipo_usuario = $_POST['tipo_usuario']; // Tipo de usuario: superusuario, cliente, banca
    $id_usuario = $_POST['id_usuario']; // ID del usuario actual
    $superior = $_POST['superior']; // ID del cliente o usuario superior
    
    if ($tipo_usuario === 'superusuario') {
        // Superusuario: ve todos los sorteos
        $whereSQL = "WHERE TRUE";
    } elseif ($tipo_usuario === 'cliente') {
        // Cliente: ve sus sorteos y los del superusuario
        $whereSQL = "WHERE id_usuario_base = $id_usuario OR superior = 0";
    } elseif ($tipo_usuario === 'banca') {
        // Banca: ve sus sorteos y los del cliente al que pertenece
        $whereSQL = "WHERE id_usuario_base = $id_usuario OR id_usuario_base = $superior";
    }
}

// Filtrar por palabra clave si aplica
if (!empty($_POST['keywords'])) {
    $keywords = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['keywords']);
    $whereSQL .= " AND nombre LIKE '%$keywords%'";
}

// Realizar la consulta
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM sorteos_base $whereSQL ORDER BY id_sorteo_base ASC");

